# What kind of activities can cause this kind of memory leak

Tags: c++, c, linux

The pmap shows that something inside leaking process allocates memory address space after process stack.

```
bfe00000    220K rw---    [ anon ]
bfe45000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
bfe5a000   1260K rw---    [ anon ]
```

I`m not able to reproduce such allocation. I used malloc() and pthread_create() but both will fail when there is no free address space before stack.

Advice on what to do next?

ps. I can not use any debuger, valgrind or sth. because the issue manifests on customer device.

edit 1. candidates are:
- mmap()
- ?

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overflow. Are you writing data past the boundaries of an array?

Comment: Looks like the stack of some thread, or a large allocation of memory directly thru `mmap`. Can you study the source code of that application???

Comment: Add logging when doing allocations, printing the pointers. Then when freeing pointers log again with the pointers.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have access to source code. The code is really big (~1M LOC) so I'm trying to find a patter to look for.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is not possible because the device is under heavy load and such debugs will kill it. Only I can do is source code analysis.

Comment: Why can't you repro it on a virtual machine (or device) and debug it there? Does it take a very long time to occur?

Comment: I would try to setup a remote debugging (`gdb` is able to do so thru a `gdbserver`), (or as Caribou suggested with an emulator). The learning & setting-up effort is worthwhile, since you'll reuse for future bugs.

Comment: @Caribou I failed to reproduce :( it could be something specific in customer load that tigers the issue.

Comment: Failing that - since it is dying on the customer device anyway, could you get a dump/core at failure and do the (admittedly painful) analysis on the core back at base? (this is something we used to do when I worked for an AV company and there were failures)

Comment: @Caribou The device should work ~70 day before reset, so I have some time. This issue is hard to debug because stack trace will fail to display because of lack of memory (it uses mmap to map ~20MB binary).

Comment: Given these constraints I can see your problem. The only way I can see that you will get closer to the area of code causing the problem is via logging as Basile/Joachim says, if you do any logging currently could you add memory usage periodically so that you can narrow down when the problem happens? I'm out of ideas TBH - good luck :o

Comment: You could use memory allocation hooks to trace the allocations. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html